# Should all "war" related tags be merged in to one?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Should both [war](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/war) and [war-crimes](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/war-crimes) be merged as synonyms for [laws-of-war](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/laws-of-war)?

- [war](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/war) has no userguidance and [nine questions](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/war).
- [war-crimes](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/war-crimes) has no user guidance and [two questions](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/war-crimes)
- [laws-of-war](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/laws-of-war) has no user guidance and [52 questions](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/laws-of-war)

I suggest that merging the first two with [laws-of-war](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/laws-of-war) would be consistent with the terminology used for [law-of-the-sea](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law-of-the-sea).

(I will add relevant user guidance if/when this proposal is considered by the community.)